# "Keep positive" in meaning of "be an optimist" works?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "**Keep positive**" in meaning of "**be an optimist**" works

The context is, when someone was failed in an exam, and I want to encourage him for the second chance that has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, **"Stay positive"** is a bit more common and natural-sounding than **"Keep positive"**, although the Ngram indicates that might be a [relatively recent trend](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+positive%2Cstay+positive&year_start=1940).

As for what the expression means, you can say that as:

- Be **an** optimist

or:

- Be **optimistic**

but I would avoid:

- Be optimist

(In other words, use an article with the noun; otherwise, use the adjectival form of the word.)

Comment: Thank you. I added the articles for focusing readers on the question.

Comment: Please see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169617/how-often-is-the-expression-get-on-well-used-is-there-any-difference-with-ge/169642#comment339358_169642) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440989/is-the-word-hitherto-outdated/440994#comment1058863_440994). In short, that's not really an *Ngram*, and be careful when drawing conclusions from the chart beyond the usual range (before 1800 and after 2000). Second of all, I think the chart is misleading because *stay positive* is mostly used in the context of encouragement, etc.

Comment: *Keep positive*, on the other hand, can be used in other contexts as well. (From Google Books:) *To stay positive it is important to **keep positive** people in your life*, *When we say that we must create and **keep positive** thoughts*, *but if we will **keep positive** attitudes in the midst of those situations*, ***Keep positive** and very inspirational people around you*, etc. However, I think that despite all that, *keep positive* might be emerging as the new *stay positive*.

Comment: @user2684291 - Sure. I was limiting my answer to a standalone usage.