# How often is the expression "get on well" used? Is there any difference with "get along"?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, expressions, british-english

I have been talking with a person from US and when I said something like this:

> They do not **get on well** with others

She didn´t understand me at first, but later she said that was a funny sentence and they do not used to say like that.

Another example with this expression:

> Choose people who are likely to be with the CMC for some time, who are steady and reliable and **get on well** with others.

I know there is another phrasal verb used for this purpose: **get along**

> Now almost everybody likes to play and **get along** with each other

- Is the expression "get on well" used with the same meaning in UK and US?
- Is there any different shade of meaning between both expressions?
- How often are both expressions used in UK/US?

**Note:** There is the chance that she said something different because this happened time ago and I do not remember very well.

Comment: Interesting [dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-along-on); it indicates either form is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions have the same meaning, but there is a significant difference in frequency of use between the US and UK.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20on%20with%20him%3A%20eng_us_2012%2Cget%20along%20with%20him%3A%20eng_us_2012%2Cget%20on%20with%20him%3A%20eng_gb_2012%2Cget%20along%20with%20him%3A%20eng_gb_2012%2Cget%20on%20well%20with%20him%3A%20eng_us_2012%2Cget%20on%20well%20with%20him%3A%20eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20on%20with%20him%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20along%20with%20him%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20on%20with%20him%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20along%20with%20him%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20on%20well%20with%20him%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20on%20well%20with%20him%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that **get along with** is the preferred expression in the US, and **get on [well] with** is the preferred expression in the UK.

Comment: Your chart isn't an n-gram.  Rather, it's comparing two different n-grams, *get on well with* and *get along with*.  N-grams are strings of n grams, in this case words.  The word *n-gram* does not specifically refer to Google Books Ngram Viewer or the charts it generates showing the frequency of n-grams over time, so although this is a good answer, it's slightly confusing as worded.

Answer (score 0):

One of the meanings of the phrasal verb "get on" is "to have a good relationship". Cambridge Dictionaries lists it for UK and US usage and mentions "get along" as a UK variant.

[Get on (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-on)